# Custom Function to download remote url data in php with fallback system

Tags: php, function, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

I am trying to create a custom function to get remote url data in variable. but i am doing this with fallback system so what are the available functions to get the remote data.

i would like to see if i am not missing something.
I am creating script to run on my clients machine so , if they dont have specific functions enabled, it should fallback to another available function ,

```
function url_get_contents ($url) {
    if (function_exists('curl_exec')){ 
        $conn = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,  true);
        curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $url_get_contents_data = (curl_exec($conn));
        curl_close($conn);
    }elseif(function_exists('file_get_contents')){
        $url_get_contents_data = file_get_contents($url);
    }elseif(function_exists('fopen') && function_exists('stream_get_contents')){
        $handle = fopen ($url, "r");
        $url_get_contents_data = stream_get_contents($handle);
    }else{
        $url_get_contents_data = false;
    }
return $url_get_contents_data;
}
```

so later i can check like this

```
$data = url_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
if($data){
echo "bravo";
}else{
echo "oops";
}
```

What are more available method/functions to get remote file data.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. This will work even with very outdated php-versions. So I'd say its pretty safe to use

Comment: so i am not missing any other function , i guess.

Comment: Yeah, right. Everything is fine

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");` A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure HTTP requests. Valid values are things like "GET", "POST", "CONNECT" and so on; i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here. For instance, entering "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be incorrect.
**Note:**
Don't do this without making sure the server supports the custom request method first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code and approach is excellent. It seemed to me safe with most of the versions of PHP.

A thing regarding the curl. Its better to use this option for ssl

```
curl_setopt($conn, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Otherwise you'll get the following error for the https protocol in some systems.

```
* SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

You can also try `fsockopen()` to get the remote content. But for this one, you have to change the for number for different protocols.

```
$fp = fsockopen($domain, $portno, $errno, $errstr);
```